# Can Google understand text which is added from a script?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello and sorry for my bad english...

Suppose I have a div with a outside script source inside it.
And in the script I print some text/links into this div.
The question is if Google can see and understand this text/links which come from a script and not a normal HTML.

Comment: if you mean that the google-bot can understand text printed or insterted using javascript then the answer is: No

Answer (score 0):

Googlebot does handle some Javascript. It's possible: http://mobile.twitter.com/mattcutts/status/131425949597179904

Answer (score 0):

Initially I would have said "no" but [according to this article](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/05/googles-bots-learn-to-read-interactive-web-pages-more-like-humans/) it looks like they now do!

> ...it appears Google's bots have been trained to act more like humans to mine interactive site content, running the JavaScript on pages they crawl to see what gets coughed up.

Can't find anything official from Google however